# How to Logon to a Website using (Excel) VBA and MSXML2.XMLHTTP

Tags: vba, authentication

I'm stuck on something that I'm sure must have been solved many times before, but for all my searching I can't seem to find the detail/documentation that I need.

I'd like to logon to a website from Excel to get some share price data.  I don't want to use the "IE Object" but want to do this with MSXML2.

The html source of the (relevant part of the) webpage, looks like this

```
<form id="login_form" method="POST" name="login_form" action="https://secure.advfn.com/login/secure">
<input id="redirect_url" type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value="aHR0cDovL3VrLmFkdmZuLmNvbS9jb21tb24vYWNjb3VudC9sb2dpbg==">
<div class="fields">
<label for="login_username">Username</label>
<input id="login_username" class="text ui-widget-content" type="text" maxlength="64" name="login_username" value="" tabindex="1">
</div>
<div class="fields">
<label for="login_password">Password</label>
<input id="login_password" class="text ui-widget-content" type="password" maxlength="16" name="login_password" value="" tabindex="2">
</div>
<div class="fields">
<input id="login_submit" class="button" type="submit" value="Log In" tabindex="3">
</div>
</form>
```

My attempt to logon looks like this

```
Set oXML = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
oXML.Open "GET", "http://uk.advfn.com/common/account/login", False
oXML.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
oXML.send "login_username=xxxxxx&login_password=xxxxx"
```

But all I seem to receive back is the original page

I have tried various permutations of this, but without success, and whilst there is documentation I haven't been able to find much specific to this kind of issue and/or code samples.

Ok, after a little experimentation I now have this code

```
Dim oXML_get
Dim oXML_post
Dim sHTML As String

' Instantiate MSXML2
Set oXML_get = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Set oXML_post = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP

' Navigate to logon page
oXML_get.Open "GET", "http://uk.advfn.com/common/account/login", False
oXML_get.send

sHTML = oXML_get.responseText

s2 = ParseText(sHTML, "<input type=""hidden"" value=""", """ name=""redirect_url""")

sendText = "login_username=xxxxxxxx&login_password=xxxxxxx" & "&redirect_url=" & s2

postUrl = "https://secure.advfn.com/login/secure?login_password=xxxxxxx&login_username=xxxxxxx&redirect_url=" & s2

oXML_post.Open "POST", "https://secure.advfn.com/login/secure", False
oXML_post.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
oXML_post.send 'sendText
```

This goes to the logon page to get the redirect_url parameter (which seems to vary).  The function ParseText extracts the value of this parameter (and URLencodes it).  I then use this in the 'POST' call - which is to a different URL.

Now I get a response (status) of 500.

Any further help appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: The form action is set to POST, and you're sending a GET request.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the response. I know I'm using GET - I've tried POST as well but with the same results. [Perhaps I should have put that code up].  I'm fairly sure I need to do something different with the 'send' command, but don't know what

Comment: You're also excluding the `redirect_url` parameter: have you tried including that?

Comment: No.  I read somewhere about a variable 'authentication token' and wondered if this might something like that.  However that value is constant - ie. it doesn't change if I leave and return to the page.  I will try it now and get back

Comment: No joy, but perhaps time for an update.  When I use GET I get back the same webpage - which perhaps isn't surprising.  When I use POST, I get a 404 not found status - and I get that with or without the redirect_url parameter

Comment: It would help to include the code for your POST

Comment: Tim, thanks again.  I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "the code for your POST".  Should I have some 'code' in the SEND statement (as well as just the userid and password parameters)?

Comment: Sorry - I only meant the VBA you'd used to perform the POST.  was it the same as you'd included but just POST instead of GET?  Your GET code above will not work since GET expects all parameters to be in the URL.

Comment: Tim, please see the edited post above that gives the latest code I am using and the latest error I am encountering.